# Alternativas a la traducción de Fundeu de "deepfake" como "ultrafalso"

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, neologismos

En un reciente artículo, la Fundéu propone usar la voz *[ultrafalso](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/ultrafalso-alternativa-a-deep-fake/)* como alternativa al anglicismo *deepfake*. Y por una vez creo que debo disentir con la Fundéu.

Personalmente, la voz *ultrafalso* me suena a "tan falso que se ve a lo lejos lo falso que es". Y, sin embargo, un *deepfake* es todo lo contrario, como el propio artículo comenta:

> La palabra deepfake alude a los sistemas informáticos que **permiten, mediante técnicas de inteligencia artificial, desarrollar vídeos manipulados extremadamente realistas**, aunque también es frecuente que se aplique a los vídeos así creados.

Las técnicas de inteligencia artificial a las que se refieren se conocen como *deep learning* o *[aprendizaje profundo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aprendizaje_profundo)*. De *deep learning* (con *deep* como *profundo*) viene *deepfake*, es decir, un *fake* hecho con técnicas de *deep learning*. De ahí que la propuesta de *ultrafalso* me resulte chocante.

Yo habría propuesto como alternativa "falsificación profunda" o "extrema", o puede que "falsificación realista", pero no desde luego lo que propone Fundéu. Pero por aunar todo el significado en un único sustantivo, ¿qué alternativas se os ocurren para traducir *deepfake* al español?

Comment: No sé, *trampantojo*?

Comment: @blonfu ya puestos, _ultrampantojo_. :-D

Comment: jajaja. Oye, pues no está nada mal

Comment: La verdad es que *ultrafalso* a mí me parece bien construido.  Aunque *ultra-* puede significa *requete-* (que para mí sí sería obviamente falso desde incluso lejos), su significado tradicional es *más allá de*.  Un *deepfake* es algo tan falso que ya parece verdadero, sin los artificios o rasgos que haría cualquier otra cosa parecer falso.  Para mí, alguien requeterrico es muy muy rico, pero es algo que todavía puedo captar en mi cabeza.  Un ultrarrico es tan rico que va más allá de mi entendimiento, ni cabe en el significado que me guarda la palabra *rico*.

Answer (score 4):

Creo que el problema es que la traducción no es totalmente correcta: si interpretamos *fake* como sinónimo de *counterfeit*, (es decir, "falsificación"),  cobra más sentido: como **ultrafalsificación**, se puede entender como una falsificación muy conseguida, difícil de detectar.

PS: El artículo enlazado ya ofrece esta opción:

> De igual modo, es posible crear otras palabras como ultrafalsear (como ultrafalsear un vídeo), ultrafalseado (como vídeo ultrafalseado) y ultrafalsificación.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que, como en otras ocasiones, no se debe buscar una traducción literal, sino más bien algo que tenga sentido dependiendo de la idea que se quiere expresar; y tomando como referencia la definición que @Charlie nos brinda:

> **... vídeos manipulados extremadamente realistas, ...**

Yo propondría: **ultrarealista**

Comment: En ese caso, ¿no sé debería escribir **ultrarrealista**, con dos 'r'?

Comment: Claro que si, mis disculpas....

Comment: No te preocupes, porque sé que era una errata. Sólo era por hacerlo ver.